# Unable to locate package libtensorflow-dev

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, apt-get

I am trying to install Tesseract from Git on Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS following the steps on [https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling---GitInstallation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling-%E2%80%93-GitInstallation).

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtensorflow-dev
```

But the command says:

> E: Unable to locate package libtensorflow-dev

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue. After a lot of searching, I found something. you can install the pkg manually from
http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/libtensorflow-dev/

I hope it helps. :)